# Polymer, how to format a URL string w/ a variable

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I want to binding a URL string like this:

like
but it not work.
what should i do?

```
  <dom-module id="list-view">
    <template id="app" testattr$="{{value}}" >
       <iron-list id="list" items="{{data}}" as="item">
         <template>
             <a href="{{item.id}}" >
                   <span>[[item.name]]</span>
             </a>


         </template>
      </iron-list>
   </template>


       <script>

        Polymer({
          is: 'list-view',
             ready: function() {
                    var _self = this;
                             $.get('data/persons.json',function(data){
                              _self.data = 
                             });
               });
            });
        </script>
 </dom-module>
```

I use iron-list element to repeat the data to list. object --> [{"id":"001","name":"adisak"},{"id":"002","name":"adisak2"},{"id":"003","name":"‌​adisak3"}] then i use iron-list to binding data in to list of element

Answer (score 1):

You can compute your URL with a method, like this:

```
<dom-module id="list-view">
  <template id="app" testattr$="{{value}}" >
     <iron-list id="list" items="{{data}}" as="item">
       <template>
         <a href="{{_computeUrl(item.id)}}" >
           <span>[[item.name]]</span>
         </a>
       </template>
    </iron-list>
 </template>
 <script>
   Polymer({
     is: 'list-view',
     ready: function() {
       var _self = this;
       $.get('data/persons.json',function(data){
         _self.data = data;
       });
     },
     _computeUrl: function(id) {
       return '/myurl/' + id;
     }
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: It was a good answer but my data properties is an array of object. I use iron-list element to repeat the data to list.                                                      object --> [{"id":"001","name":"adisak"},{"id":"002","name":"adisak2"},{"id":"003","name":"adisak3"}]                                                                            then i use iron-list to binding data in to list of element. I think i can't use "computed" function for this problem. Sorry for my eng.  :)

Comment: In that case you can create a function that accepts one item in the array and computes the URL accordingly. In the attribute binding it will look like `href="{{_computeLink(item)}}"`.

Comment: how to create a function that binding data like {{_computeLink(item)}}  .       Where should i read in document, sorry i can't find the article like this in polymer doc.

Comment: Please update your question to include all of the relevant code, so that I can provide an example best suited to your situation.